# Layer 3 POE+ Network Switch Advice

Tags: networking, ethernet, switch

G'day all, I'm currently in the process of designing a network for a fully accessible smart-home for disability. It's quite a complex setup and where I'm getting a bit stuck is finding a suitable network switch at a reasonable price so I'm here looking for some advice. I'll list the requirements below to give you an idea of what I'm looking for:

#### Network switch requirements:

**Layer 3 for multiple VLAN support** - the plan is for 3 VLANs;
VLAN0 for general internet access,
VLAN1 for smart home devices (all off the cloud so no internet access required),
VLAN2 for the security devices (must not have any internet access).

**At least 8 POE 802.3at for security cameras and wireless APs** - there will be 4 security cameras that require POE 802.3af and 4 wireless APs that require POE 802.3at;
All 4 security cameras will be on VLAN2,
2 APs will be on VLAN0,
1 AP will be on VLAN1,
1 AP will be on VLAN2.
All wireless APs are HP 560 J9846A and because there are several 3x3 MIMO devices being connected they will require POE 802.3at (the spec sheet lists this requirement for 3x3 MIMO).

**At least 20 Gigabit Ethernet ports** - The switch will be located in a rack that contains a lot of the smart home controllers and hubs as well as a file server and several other networking devices including the router so a rack mountable switch is preferred but not required, all of the devices in the rack are connected via Ethernet as well as each room in the building has Ethernet ports in the walls that connect to an outlet in the room that contains the rack.

**No cloud or online account requirements** - One of the requirements of this house is that all of the smart home and security devices must function without internet access if ever it goes down (there are also these kinds of requirements for water and power) so any devices that require any kind of cloud access to function or even to sign up with an account or anything like that are out of the question unfortunately, so it's easier to just avoid those devices entirely.

#### Budget and other notes:

This has been one of the most difficult aspects as most things (particularly smart home devices) require some kind of cloud access or account signups, so far everything else has been sorted except for the network switch because it has been quite overwhelming trying to find an appropriate switch that meets all of these requirements while staying within the budget of which I'm hoping to spend AUD $2000 at most on the switch itself if possible.

If you need any further information about the requirements or current network setup plans let me know, I'd rather share as little as possible as this is intended for maximum security and it would be irresponsible of me to share all the details in a public place, but if there is something specific that would help you to recommend a switch do let me know. The deadline for completion is 10th of January so we need to make sure that any adjustments or modifications that might need to be made to the house infrastructure is done before the years end and any changes I make to the networking equipment will require approval from a third party company that specializes in disability and are the ones putting in all of these restrictions, they usually take about 2 weeks to approve or deny so I'm starting to run out of time. Any recommendations or advice specifically about the network switch would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you so much for reading all of this, I've tried to be as detailed as I can with the info I think is important.

Comment: You're pretty much looking at a professional grade switch. Couple of things worth considering, whether you're willing to go second hand and if the POE stuff can use an injector.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek | A Professional grade switch is fine, a lot of the equipment would already be considered in that category, the only issue we are running into now is quickly approaching the budget we were set. They have allowed the use of used equipment so long as it's not more than 5 years old which shouldn't be much of a problem so I'm certainly open to considering a used switch if necessary. As for injectors, that's something I looked into and while certainly a possibility I would prefer to reduce the amount equipment as much as possible so combining is preferred but not a requirement.

Comment: I should clarify for anyone else reading this that the budget has almost been reached so if possible spending no more than $2000 on the switch itself. Another thing is that the funding is coming from a third party organization and there is no negotiation when it comes to the budget and the rules set in place by them, however there is a lot of freedom within those rules to choose any brand/products that are suitable. Also, each separate network device needs it's own power point that will be connected to a large UPS so fewer is better as they need to be requested and put in by an electrician.

Answer (score 1):

While I've not used it *personally*, I've used some of their other gear which runs the same basic software and I suspect Microtik's CRS354-48G-4S+2Q+RM meets and exceeds your requirements in every way. [Serve At Home's got an in depth review](https://www.servethehome.com/mikrotik-crs354-48p-4s-2q-rm-review/2/)

**Layer 3 for multiple VLAN support** - the reviews mention there's a performance drop but this has both 40 and 10 gig ports, and you're essentially using 'only' half the gigabit ports. Ought to have no issues handling your needs tho this is something to check further before pulling the trigger.

**At least 8 POE 802.3at for security cameras and wireless APs** - this supports POE on all 48 ports.

**At least 20 Gigabit Ethernet ports** - 48 gigabit ports, in addition to faster ports.

**No cloud or online account requirements** - Router OS is entirely locally managed, either via a web UI,command line or [winbox](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Winbox).

**Budget and other notes** A quick google search suggests this is between 1.3 to 1.9k AUD, and the US RRP is a hair under 1000 USD. I'd also add this seems to run off a single 800w PSU. Redundancy wasn't a requirement mentioned tho

Comment: | Thank you for the recommendation, from your description that sounds like the kind of switch I'm looking for and well within budget too. I'll have a look into it now.